# After enabling Google Tag Manager, Paypal Express checkout breaks

Tags: paypal-express, onestepcheckout, enterprise-1.14, google-tag-manager

When going through the one step checkout process, Paypal Express is encountering an error where the page is not being properly redirected.

By debugging into opcheckout.js, in the function `setStepResponse`, this line was stopping execution of all JS:

```
$('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
```

Some additional debugging showed that `response.update_section.name` was undefined.

By adding a custom observer to the hook `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout` and ensuring a name is set, I was able to fix this problem.

The Enterprise extension `GoogleAnalyticsUniversal` has an observer tied to the same event that calls the function `setGoogleAnalyticsOnCheckout`.  It appears that this function is causing the problem.

Is this a bug in Enterprise?  Or is it possible the data is "corrupted" upstream by a custom extension?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the code of the `setGoogleAnalyticsOnCheckout` function since the code is part of Enterprise.

Comment: Ryre - We just ran into this as well. I've placed a support ticket with Magento and will report back on anything we find.  This site is on 1.14.2.2, what version are you seeing this issue in?  And did you find a fix?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to follow up!  I just posted the answer I received from support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Magento's Enterprise support, it was confirmed this is a bug between GTM and Paypal Express.

I was able to fix this problem by creating an observer on `setGoogleAnalyticsOnCheckout` in `Enterprise_GoogleAnalyticsUniversal_Model_Observer`.  The `saveBilling` function has this line:

```
$body['update_section']['name'] = 'shipping';
```

My observer uses the same logic as this line to add a name to `savePayment` which fixes the broken javascript and allows the checkout process to continue.

I did receive a patch from Magento that resolves the problem in a similar fashion (it modifies core code instead of creating an observer), but I'm unsure if I'm allowed to share it.  The name of the patch is "PATCH_SUPEE-6717_EE_1.14.2.0_v1.sh".

Comment: Haha - We just got the same answer.  Thanks!